# How to get a view over a slice with an added head and tail?

Tags: rust

I am trying to get a "view" of a slice (i.e. no copying) that contains a prepended head element as well as a last element appended to it.

I know how to express this using Groovy (probably Ruby also) syntax:

```
def elements = [ 'a', 'b' ]
def result = [ 'head', *elements, 'tail' ]
assert result == [ 'head', 'a', 'b', 'tail' ]
```

The `*` above is the spread operator.

In Rust, this seems a little harder... I can only find solutions where I copy the slice into a mutable vector, then push and insert the tail and head.

I was hoping it would be possible to use an iterable or something that just appears to contain the elements I want as in the example above... Is it possible in Rust? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you need is an iterator, you can use [`iter::once`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/fn.once.html) and [`Iterator::chain`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.chain):

```
use std::iter;

fn main() {
    let elements = ["a", "b"];
    let head = iter::once("head");
    let tail = iter::once("tail");
    let result = head.chain(elements.iter().cloned()).chain(tail);

    assert!(["head", "a", "b", "tail"].iter().cloned().eq(result));
}
```

I also had to use `cloned` because the `Iterator::Item` of an array is a reference to the value, thus a `&&str`. `cloned` converts back to a `&str`.

---

> Is it possible in Rust?

It is absolutely not possible to construct a slice with "extra" elements.

A *slice*, by definition, is a range of values that are **contiguous in memory**. Its literal definition is a pointer to the start of the data and the number of elements. There's simply no location to store an "extra" element.

Comment: But notice that I never asked for a slice back, I asked for a "view" (not sure if `Iterator` was the right word in Rust for that). So the first part of the answer is not necessary.

Comment: @Renato questions and answers on Stack Overflow aren't meant just for you, the asker or me, the answerer. They are meant for *every person who comes after us*. To that end, answers have to "color a *little* beyond the edges" to help all those people who are going to find your question through a search engine, read the title, then skip directly to the answer. I agree that I can flip the order of the two sections.